# How to use vuejs global event to notify after redirection

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have created a global vuejs event named `EvenBus` in a file called `app.js` as follows:

```
window.EventBus = new Vue();
```

After deleting a person from a database, I redirect to the `home` page and I emit an event called `deleted` like so:

```
import {app} from '../app';
export default {
methods: {
    deleteMe: function () {
        axios.delete('/api/persons/' + this.person.id)
        .then(response => {
            window.location.href = '/home';

            EventBus.$emit('deleted', {
                notification_msg: 'This person has been successfully deleted.',
            });
        })
},
}
```

on the page home, I have inserted a tag `<notify></notify>` linked to a component called `notify.vue`.
In this component, I added the following script:

```
import {app} from '../app';
export default {
/* ... */
mounted() {
    let that = this;
    console.log(EventBus);
    EventBus.$on('deleted', function(data){
        alert('person deleted!!' + data.notification_msg);
        that.msg_text = data.notification_msg;
    });
},
}
```

When the delete happens, I get successfully redirected to the `home` page, but nothing happens there. The `alert('person deleted!!...')` never shows up.
The code is executed with no error.

Am I missing something to make my component listen to the emitted event?

**EDIT**
The line `console.log(EvenBus);` written in the `notify.vue` file shows that there is a event called 'deleted' (c.f. printscreen below) [image]

Comment: Redirecting to the `/home` causes a page load yes?

Comment: yes, it loaded as an http request. It's not done using ajax or anything. Only `window.location.href = '/home';`

Comment: So...The event you emitted is basically gone because the page is gone, if it even emits it.

Comment: alright I understand. Please add your comment as an answer so I can make if as answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that when this line of code is executed,

```
window.location.href = '/home';
```

the page you are on is replaced with the `/home` page. So, it's possible it never even gets to the line that emits the event and if it does, the object that listens to the event is gone when the page is loaded.

You might want to look into using VueRouter so that the page isn't destroyed. Other than that, possibly tell the server when you are redirecting that it needs to show the notification when the page is loaded.

Comment: I've just edited my original question by adding a print screen to it. If the event is gone as you suggest, how come I can see an event called `deleted` after the redirect? the line `console.log(EventBus)` is written inside the component `notify`.

Comment: @Warrio The console is showing the *handler* you registered with `$on`.

Comment: That's unfortunately true :D. Thank you!